# How to get Average Salary of SQL HourlyPayRate Column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am working on creating a SSRS report and I want to get the Average of the HourlyPayRate Column that I have(in my case statement). I am a self learner of SQL and was wondering how I can get the AVG of the HourlyPayRate in a new table(If even possible).

```
DECLARE @PROCLEVEL varchar(6),
                   @HRYEAR varchar(5),
                           @HRPERIOD varchar(15)
SET @PROCLEVEL = 'XXX'
SET @HRYEAR = '2019'
SET @HRPERIOD = '03'
SELECT CASE
           WHEN HRPERIOD = 3 THEN 'March'
           WHEN HRPERIOD = 6 THEN 'June'
           WHEN HRPERIOD = 9 THEN 'September'
           WHEN HRPERIOD = 12 THEN 'DECEMBER'
       END HRPERIOD,
       EMPLOYEE,
       HRYEAR,
       PAY_RATE,
       FTE_TOTAL,
       JOB_CLASS_NAME,
       JOB_CLASS,
       SALARY_CLASS,
       CASE
           WHEN SALARY_CLASS = 'S'
                OR PAY_RATE > 1000 THEN (PAY_RATE / 2080)
           ELSE PAY_RATE
       END AS HourlyPayRate
FROM [LAWSONDWHR].[dbo].[RPT_EMPLOYEECENSUS_ASOF]
WHERE PROCESS_LEVEL = @PROCLEVEL
  AND HRYEAR = @HRYEAR
  AND HRPERIOD = @HRPERIOD
  AND JOB_CLASS = 'RN'
  AND FTE_TOTAL != 0
  AND MASTER_EMP_STATUS NOT IN ('ZZ',
                                'T1')
ORDER BY PAY_RATE
```

What I am doing is doing is when the Employee's Salary class is an 'S' for salary or if the pay rate is greater than 1000 then take the pay rate / 2080 the number of hours in a year.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what you mean by "in a new table"? Do you mean calculate it outside of this sp?

Comment: @wavery basically I just want it to calculate the average. Whichever way works the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you not just do some form of this? I have removed your variables and where clause but you can adjust as needed:

```
Select Employee, AVG(HourlyPayRate)
from (
SELECT CASE
       WHEN HRPERIOD = 3 THEN 'March'
       WHEN HRPERIOD = 6 THEN 'June'
       WHEN HRPERIOD = 9 THEN 'September'
       WHEN HRPERIOD = 12 THEN 'DECEMBER'
   END HRPERIOD,
   EMPLOYEE,
   HRYEAR,
   PAY_RATE,
   FTE_TOTAL,
   JOB_CLASS_NAME,
   JOB_CLASS,
   SALARY_CLASS,
   CASE
       WHEN SALARY_CLASS = 'S'
            OR PAY_RATE > 1000 THEN (PAY_RATE / 2080)
       ELSE PAY_RATE
   END AS HourlyPayRate
FROM [LAWSONDWHR].[dbo].[RPT_EMPLOYEECENSUS_ASOF]
)
GROUP BY Employee
```

Comment: I am sorry I am new to SQL, would I add that select statement below my original select statement then? under the order by PAY_RATE?

Comment: The HourlyPayRate Column is coming from my case statement when the Salary Class = 'S' (which is salary) it is dividing the Salary by 2080 to get the HourlyPayRate. (so if someone made 50k a year, it would give them the hourly rate for that person). Am I able to select the new column I had created to get an average from that? If I am, how do I put that select statement in the SQL query above?

Comment: If you want the average by employee you would need to add employee to your select like: Select Employee, AVG(HourlyPayRate) as AvgPayPerEmployee from (Your Query) group by Employee. I can update the answer if you like.

Comment: Yes that would be awesome!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the average hourly pay for each employee, you can use `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT Employee, AVG(HourlyPayRate) AS AvgHourlyRate
FROM (
    { your query }
) a
GROUP BY Employee
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution, but if you are using TSQL (SQL Server), and you are willing to run with the assumption that all employees work the same number of hours in a year (that is usually not a fully correct assumption by the way), you can just wrap HourlyPayRate in the AVG() function ...